# Will the result be implementation-defined if one or two of the operands of the / or % operator are negative numbers?

Tags: c, divide, ansi-c

e.g. What are the values of these expressions? Do they depend on the compiler?

```
-7/3   -7%3
7/-3   7%-3
-7/-3  -7%-3
```

Answer (score 6):

In C89, the result of division `/` can be truncated either way for negative operands.

In C99 or later, the result will be truncated toward zero.

The `%` operator depends on the behavior of `/` in all standards.

---

References:

> C89 § 3.3.5
>
> If either operand is negative, whether the result of the `/` operator is the largest integer less than or equal to the algebraic quotient or the smallest integer greater than or equal to the algebraic quotient is implementation-defined, as is the sign of the result of the `%` operator. If the quotient `a/b` is representable. the expression `(a/b) * b + a%b` shall equal `a`.

And

> C11 § 6.5.5
>
> When integers are divided, the result of the `/` operator is the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded

with a footnote:

> This is often called "truncation toward zero"

Comment: Thanks a lot. So C99 requires '-7/3 == -2  7/-3 == -2  -7/-3 == 2'  right?

Answer (score 1):

The result will depend on the language specification you compiler adheres to. Operators `/` and `%` are tied to each other by the following relationship

```
(a / b) * b + (a % b) == a
```

Standard C89/90 says that the result of the division is implementation-defined: the compiler is allowed to implement either Euclidean division (truncation towards negative infinity, non-negative remainder), or Fortran-style division (truncation towards zero, possibly negative remainder).

In Euclidean division

```
-7/3 = -3  -7%3 = 2
7/-3 = -2  7%-3 = 1
-7/-3 = 3 -7%-3 = 2
```

In Fortran-style division

```
-7/3 = -2  -7%3 = -1
7/-3 = -2  7%-3 = 1
-7/-3 = 2 -7%-3 = -1
```

Standard C99 (and later) requires all C compilers to implement Fortran-style division.

Side note: C++ sticks to implementation-defined specification all the way through C++03. C++11 mandates Fortran-style division though.

Comment: Thanks. I was going to ask what the rules in C++ about that are.

Answer (score 0):

Since % depends on / (They really are the same operation, / returns the quotient while % returns the remainder.) then what you get is based on the operands that were supplied.  C follows rules of algebra, so the following is true:

- The order of operations follows PEMDAS: Parenthesis, Exponent, Multiply/Divide, Add/Subtract.
- For Multiply/Divide, two positive or negative numbers result in a positive number.  One positive and one negative number results in a negative answer.